# Mechanism - Dialkyne boron complex + Iodine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Exam tomorrow and I was flicking through one of our handouts to find this reaction (D). I'm certain we don't need to know the mechanism but I was quite inquisitive as to how the iodination works.

The hydroboration part is fine, I just don't understand how it fuses the two alkynes.

I've tried to work it through as in the reaction above (C)

[image: Funky Dialkyne boron rn]

Comment: I am not that sure but I suppose first iodine acts upon one of the triple bond . Now the carbon attached to iodine as well as boron gets partial positive charge due to which the the bond between the other carbon and the boron probably rearranges to bond with the carbon connected to Iodine and boron. Later I suppose another partial positive iodine attracts the partial negative iodine and the bond goes back to form triple bond thereby breaking the C-B bond too and left with the product....